# spring boot multi module spring-boot-maven-plugin compilation failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I have a multi module project with maven and spring boot.

My main pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.emo.kazi</groupId>
        <artifactId>kazi-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>kazi</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <modules>
        <module>kazi-core</module>
        <module>kazi-api</module>
        <module>kazi-service</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.kazi.Application</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Build failure by the first module with dependency to another module:

```
[INFO] kazi ............................................... SUCCESS [  2.186 s]
[INFO] kazi-core .......................................... SUCCESS [  4.640 s]
[INFO] kazi-api ........................................... FAILURE [  1.415 s]
[INFO] kazi-service ....................................... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.869 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-01-24T12:21:48+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project kazi-api: Compilation failure: Compilation failure: 
[ERROR] /../RegistrationRepository.java:[3,30] package com.kazi.core.entities does not exist
[ERROR] /../RegistrationRepository.java:[6,63] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol: class Registration
```

`kazi-core` is a module without dependency to another module, `kazi-api` has a dependency to `kazi-core` and `kazi-service` a dependency to `kazi-api`

core pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.emo.kazi</groupId>
        <artifactId>kazi</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>kazi-core</artifactId>
    <version>${parent.version}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>kazi-core</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

kazi-api pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.emo.kazi</groupId>
        <artifactId>kazi</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>kazi-api</artifactId>
    <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>kazi-api</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emo.kazi</groupId>
            <artifactId>kazi-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
                    <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>1.18.16</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>-Amapstruct.suppressGeneratorTimestamp=true</arg>
                        <arg>-Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring</arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

service pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.emo.kazi</groupId>
        <artifactId>kazi</artifactId>
        <version>0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>kazi-service</artifactId>
    <version>${parent.version}</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>kazi-service</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.emo.kazi</groupId>
            <artifactId>kazi-api</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

my parent pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.emo.kazi</groupId>
    <artifactId>kazi-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- GrantedAuthority wird in kazi project bei Role verwendet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.16</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-plugin-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

When a skipped the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` it works fine:

```
<plugin>
          <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

My `Application.class` main class is in the core module.

How i have to use a `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in multi module project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `spring-boot-maven-plugin` only in modules where you have main classes.
Do not use the plugin in libs modules.

According to the current behavior: when you are using the plugin in the parent pom file, you automatically apply this plugin step for each nested module.

Comment: i have removed the plugin from all pom.xml and left it only in core module with main class and got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar issue, it resolved for me.

1. Keep the spring-boot-maven-plugin only in modules containing your main class. Remove it from all other modules.
2. Update executable configuration in the spring-boot-maven-plugin like below.

   ```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <executable>true</executable>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
   ```

Comment: sorry but it didn't help ;-(